# What means if [ "x/usr/bin" != "x" ] in bash script?

Tags: bash

I'm trying to understand some sequence of bash scripts, and on one of the steps there is a condition:

```
if [ "x/usr/bin" != "x" ]; then <do some actions>
```

What do the following mean?

- `x` in `x/usr/bin`
- `x` in the right hand side of the testing equation?

Comment: It's a simple comparisions of strings. Since the result is always true, the if-statement looks somehow superfluous, I think this line is produced by a parser. Take a look at [this similar question](https://askubuntu.com/q/1169260/590937).

Comment: Thank you @mook765, both older thread suggested by you and the reply below are very nice and complement each other.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a well known bashism.

If a variable (say `$foo` in this example) might be empty or might hold a value,

If `foo=""`, then

```
 if [ "$foo" = "bar" ]
```

expands to

```
if [ = "bar" ]
```

a syntax error :-(

If one uses

```
if [ "x$foo" = "xbar" ]
```

it expands to

```
if [ "x" = "xbar" ]
```

No syntax error.

There are better ways to check for empty variables, like

```
if [[ -n "$foo" ]]
```

Comment: If `foo=""`, then `if [ "$foo" = "bar" ]` expands to `if [ "" = "bar" ]` in bash, which is perfectly fine. This x trick is kept around by cargo culting a fix for some ancient broken shell.

Comment: Thank you @waltinator, it's a very nice addition which explains the older thread which was suggested as the answer.

Comment: @muru, but as explained in the answer, foo maybe empty.

Comment: [[ ]] is bash specific, x way can be used in sh too.

Comment: @Martian2020 that is not a problem in *any* POSIX shell.

Comment: @muru, I've checked after my comment and `"$foo"` is not empty for `if` even if `$foo` is, so I see your point of "no problem". Maybe I misunderstood your first comment.